# Use grep to find content in files and move them if they match

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, grep

I'm using grep to generate a list of files I need to move:

```
grep -L -r 'Subject: \[SPAM\]' .
```

How can I pass this list to the mv command and move the files somewhere else?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If you want to find and move files that do not match your pattern (move files that don't contain `'Subject \[SPAM\]'` in this example) use:

```
grep -L -Z -r 'Subject: \[SPAM\]' . | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} DIR
```

The -Z means output with zeros (\0) after the filenames (so spaces are not used as delimeters).

```
xargs -0
```

means interpret \0 to be delimiters.

The -L means find files that do not match the pattern.  Replace `-L` with `-l` if you want to move files that match your pattern.

Then

```
-I{} mv {} DIR
```

means replace `{}` with the filenames, so you get `mv filenames DIR`.

Comment: Thanks, the capital -I should me lowercase on my xargs

Comment: In my xargs, -i is deprecated. But sandrv may have an older version (thus, YMMV).

Comment: Shouldn't it be -l instead of -L?

Comment: I think that the asker was trying to look for files without the [SPAM] subject and move those so the answer keeping this is correct. yes though... -l would probably make sense as the default.

Answer (score 24):

This alternative works where xargs is not availabe:

```
grep -L -r 'Subject: \[SPAM\]' . | while read f; do mv "$f" out; done
```

Answer (score 11):

This is what I use in Fedora Core 12:

```
grep -l 'Subject: \[SPAM\]' | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' DIR
```

Answer (score 7):

This is what helped me:

`grep -lir 'spam' ./ | xargs mv -t ../spam`

Of course, I was already in required folder (that's why `./`) and moved them to neighboring folder. But you can change them to any paths.

I don't know why accepted answer didn't work. Also I didn't have spaces and special characters in filenames - maybe this will not work.

Stolen here: [Grep command to find files containing text string and move them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56906)

Answer (score 4):

```
mv `grep -L -r 'Subject: \[SPAM\]' .` <directory_path>
```

Assuming that the grep you wrote returns the files paths you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work:

```
mv $(grep -l 'Subject: \[SPAM\]' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}') your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways but here is a slow but failsafe one :

```
IFS=$'\n'; # set the field separator to line break
for $mail in $(grep -L -r 'Subject: \[SPAM\]' .); do mv "$mail" your_dir; done;
IFS=' '; # restore FS
```

Answer (score 0):

Work perfect fo me :

- move files who contain the text withe the word MYSTRINGTOSEARCH to directory MYDIR.

  find . -type f -exec grep -il 'MYSTRINGTOSEARCH' {} \; -exec mv {} MYDIR/ \;

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the result to the next command by using
grep ... | xargs mv {} destination

Check man xargs for more info.