# How to find and move all files matching given Beginning Of File (BOF) string?

Tags: bash

How to move all files which content begins with `foo` to another folder with command line ?

I tried this to echo filenames when matching:

```
for f in *.txt; do if [ $(head -c5 $f) = "foo" ]; then echo $f; fi; done;
```

but I'm often getting this error:

```
-bash: [: too much arguments
```

Comment: @Inian I usually use `grep` to find file content but I don't get how to move files containing the matching pattern, something like `BOF^user:` in my case.

Comment: Would this help - [Use grep to find content in files and move them if they match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/91899/5291015)

Comment: @Inian yes, but how would you apply it to Beginning Of File (BOF) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Perl one-liner in combination with `find` and `xargs`, like so:

```
echo foo > 1.txt
echo "foo\nbar" > 2.txt
echo "bar\nfoo" > 3.txt
mkdir foodir
find .  -maxdepth 1 -name '[123].txt' -exec perl -lne 'print $ARGV if /^foo/; last;' {} \; | xargs -I{} mv {} foodir 
find foodir -type f
# foodir/2.txt
# foodir/1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, however I finally fixed it by using: `for f in *.txt; do if [ "\`head -c5 $f\`" = "foo" ]; then mv $f ../tmp2/; fi; done;`

Answer (score 0):

Find with awk

```
find . -type f -exec awk -F \/ "NR < 6 && /foo/ { fnd=1 } END { if (fnd==1) { split(FILENAME,arr,\"/\");print \"mv -f \"FILENAME\" newdir/\"arr[length(arr)] } }" '{}' \;
```

Use awk to process the first 5 lines (NR < 6). Search for foo and if it exists, set a fnd variable to 1. At the end, if fnd is 1, print the mv command, using split to get the filename without the directories. Check that everything looks as expected and then run with:

```
find . -type f -exec awk -F \/ "NR < 6 && /foo/ { fnd=1 } END { if (fnd==1) { split(FILENAME,arr,\"/\");print \"mv -f \"FILENAME\" newdir/\"arr[length(arr)] } }" '{}' \; | bash
```